# When using OwnsMany within Entity Framework does table splitting occur?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, owned-types

I am observing that OwnsOne creates the owned entity inline within the owning table but using OwnsMany results in a separate table. From the official documentation I expected both methods to result in a single table by default.

For instance given

```
public class Author
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Book Book { get; set; }
    
}

public class Book
{
    public string Title { get; set; }  
}

public class AuthorConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Author>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Author> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(m=>m.Id);
        builder.OwnsOne(m => m.Book, n =>
        {
            n.WithOwner().HasForeignKey("AuthorId");
        });
    }
}
```

I get a table that looks like this

```
Author
(
    "Id" integer,
    "Book_Title" text
);
```

When I use OwnsMany with an author class that has a list of books instead

```
public class Author
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Book> Books { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class AuthorConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Author>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Author> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(m=>m.Id);
        builder.OwnsMany(m => m.Books, n =>
        {
            n.WithOwner().HasForeignKey("AuthorId");
        });
    }
}
```

I get a separate Author and Book table, where the Book table looks like

```
"Book"
(
    "AuthorId" integer NOT NULL,
    "Id" integer NOT NULL ,
    "Title" text NOT NULL
}
```

Does anyone know if OwnsMany should produce a separate table.

My database is Postgres incidentially.

Comment: Let me ask a counterquestion: if an author has 15 books, how would you expect one table to look like? So, yes, it's normal, even though in Postgres *maybe* this could be modeled as an array-column of a user-defined type, but EF won't get that specific.

Comment: What's the thinking behind that question? Are you just curious or are you trying to prevent getting a new table? Or do you want to have a new table for OwnsOne, too?